# Error: Signature verification failed while mint NFT

Tags: spl-token, nft, signature, mint

I created a candymachine v3 with sugar and I am trying to mit using the following code:

```
 const { nft } = await metaplex.candyMachines().mint({
  candyMachine,
  collectionUpdateAuthority: candyMachine.authorityAddress,
});

setNft(nft);
```

The following error is returned:

```
Error: Signature verification failed
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the other parts of your setup?
You can also try referencing this `MintNFTs.js` page from the `mint-ui-example` repo provided by metaplex: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-examples/blob/main/mint-ui-example/pages/MintNFTs.js

Comment: Reference has already been made to the `MintNFTs.js` page from the `mint-ui-example` repo provided by metaplex. Everything else works except this function where you try to minify an Nft from a v3 candy machine created with sugar cli.
I should also add that this problem has only been occurring for a few days, before that the mint function worked perfectly.

Comment: same issue here , any updates.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue is for me using this example from Metaplex [(https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-examples/tree/main/mint-ui-example)](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-examples/tree/main/mint-ui-example)

The issue is with the WalletIdentity-Provider because when I use KeyPairIdentity-Provider I am able to mint the NFT on the backend.

Any help is appreciated.
I am using phantom wallet with this which is connected on DEVNET cluster.
Tried to add custom signer option with the feePayer but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. Any idea updates on this issue?